# Nesting Specific Elements into another list in r

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a data set that has 5 `ID`s and span from `01-01-2010` to `12-31-2013`. I first `split` the data by `ID`, and end up with a list object. I then create another list that creates 10-day intervals and is arranged by `ID`.

I would like to nest these intervals into the first list of `ID`s based on the `ID`s labelled within the interval elements.

For example:
The main list consist of the `ID`s as the elements. The `[1]`,`[2]`,`[3]` are the intervals for the `ID` that is nested in. For example, in `[A]` the intervals are all for the `ID` A, for `[B]` it is for B, for `[C]` it is for C, etc..

```
[A]
   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
[B]
   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
[C]
   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
[D]
   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
[E]
   [1]
   [2]
   [3]
```

The code below nests the intervals into the `ID` list, but it nest all of the `ID`s and not the specific ones that it should be in.

```
set.seed(12345)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

date <- rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500)
ID <- rep(c("A","B","C","D", "E"), 100)

df <- data.frame(date = date,
                 x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
                 y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000),
                 ID)

df_ID <- split(df, df$ID)


df_nested <- lapply(df_ID, function(x){
  x %>%
    arrange(ID) %>% 
    # Creates a new column assigning the first day in the 10-day interval in which
    # the date falls under (e.g., 01-01-2010 would be in the first 10-day interval
    # so the `floor_date` assigned to it would be 01-01-2010)
    mutate(new = floor_date(date, "10 days")) %>%
    # For any months that has 31 days, the 31st day would normally be assigned its 
    # own interval. The code below takes the 31st day and joins it with the 
    # previous interval. 
    mutate(new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)) %>% 
    group_by(new, .add = TRUE) %>%
    group_split()
})
```

Comment: Suggest you give explicit illustrative example of 1) ID dataset, 2) the 10 day interval dataset and finally 3) the expected output. May be appropriate to link with previous related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69004964/nesting-intervals-into-a-list-of-items-by-association?noredirect=1#comment122014225_69004964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
set.seed(12345)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

f = function(data){
  data %>% mutate(
    new = floor_date(data$date, "10 days"),
    new = if_else(day(new) == 31, new - days(10), new)
  )
}

tibble(
  ID = rep(c("A","B","C","D", "E"), 100),
  date = rep_len(seq(dmy("01-01-2010"), dmy("31-12-2013"), by = "days"), 500),
  x = runif(length(date), min = 60000, max = 80000),
  y = runif(length(date), min = 800000, max = 900000)
) %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, f)) %>% 
  unnest(data)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 500 x 5
# Groups:   ID [5]
   ID    date            x       y new       
   <chr> <date>      <dbl>   <dbl> <date>    
 1 A     2010-01-01 74418. 820935. 2010-01-01
 2 A     2010-01-06 63327. 885896. 2010-01-01
 3 A     2010-01-11 60691. 873949. 2010-01-11
 4 A     2010-01-16 69250. 868411. 2010-01-11
 5 A     2010-01-21 69075. 876142. 2010-01-21
 6 A     2010-01-26 67797. 829892. 2010-01-21
 7 A     2010-01-31 75860. 843542. 2010-01-21
 8 A     2010-02-05 67233. 882318. 2010-02-01
 9 A     2010-02-10 75644. 826283. 2010-02-01
10 A     2010-02-15 66424. 853789. 2010-02-11
```

Simple and clear, isn't it?

Everything you want to do with data is included in the `f` function. You can extend it as needed.

The rest is done in a simple scheme
`tibble %>% group_by %>% nest % mutate %>% unnest`